# How to access GCP Reseller Billing

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I would like to create a GCP cost management platform for resellers/MSP. The platform will pule cost data per each of the reseller's end customers.
Where Can I find information on:

1. How can I access the reseller's data?
2. What is the data structure? Does a reseller have one dataset for all of his customers, or one dataset per customer?
3. What are the needed credentials that the reseller needs to provide in order to fetch his customers data, and what permissions need to be provided?

Answer (score 0):

I created a Video Lab on Google Cloud Billing. The first step is to understand how billing works in Google Cloud. Then understand how Identity and Access Management works so that you know what roles you need for credentials to access billing APIs.

[Google Cloud Billing](https://www.jhanley.com/videolabs/Google-Cloud-Billing/)

Review the following documentation links for technical API details:

[Get Started with the Cloud Billing API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/getting-started)

[Cloud Billing API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/)

[APIs & Reference](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/apis)

To access reseller information you will need to become a Google Partner first. Then request documentation.

Comment: Thank you Jhon. I'm building a product that will allow GCP partners to see their customer's data. I'm not managing GCP customers myself. So question is, assuming the reseller works with my platform, what info he need to provide me with in order for me to see all of his customers data and fetch it with APIs? And also generally asking, doe's a reseller has 1 dataset for all of his customers, or dataset per customer?

Comment: There is only one dataset for all the customers (https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/cost-table) and you should use subaccounts (https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/concepts#subaccounts) to get data per customer. For your API designing, you can query the bill using the exported bill in BigQuery - https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery and apply filters per subaccount (use the field billing_account_id). See here some queries examples: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/bq-examples